# Listing all sequences in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sequence

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sequences
```

I get:

> Error: The "variant" data type is not supported.
>   SQLState:  08S01
>   ErrorCode: 0

I know there are sequences. Is there a way to see sequences of a table in SQL Server Management Studio in the GUI somehow? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I noticed that this doesn't work with SQL Squirrel client program but the very same query can be used succesfully in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to know the sequences and values, you can cast the variant types. For example the following will give most of the details you may be looking for:

```
SELECT
  name,
  cast(start_value AS NUMERIC)   AS start_value,
  cast(increment AS NUMERIC)     AS increment,
  cast(current_value AS NUMERIC) AS current_value
FROM sys.sequences;
```

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting bigint to data type numeric.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire Do you remember what version that is with?  Sorry not to ask 2 years ago!

Comment: It has nothing to do with its version. It is vulnerable to be overflowed.

Comment: Okay. That's going to be a bit database to get that. It certainly worked for me when I needed it.

Answer (score 16):

You can find sequences in SSMS in object explorer under Programmability:

[image]

Comment: This is of course always an option, if you just want to see them. If you want to use them in apps, you must know how to query them ;)

Answer (score 4):

What SQL Server are you using? From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sequences-transact-sql): *In SQL Server 2005 and later versions, the visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission.* Are you sure you are running the script with proper permissions?

Comment: I actually I just noticed the following:
I used SQL Squirrel at first. The query didn't work in that.
Then I tried the exact same query in SQL Management Studio an it worked. I got the list I wanted.

It could have something to do how I authorize myself in each client or just in the different ways they access the database engine.

Comment: Oh, SQL Squirrel. Yep, probably the program didn't have permissions.